# In PHP, how can I return multiple column values from MySQL in JSON format?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I'm trying to return a list of all of the courses a user is enrolled in (course1, course2, etc.) Currently, I have the following code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","username","password","sampleTest");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Can't connect to SQL Server. Error Code %s\n", mysqli_connect_error($mysqli));
    exit;
}
// Set the default namespace to utf8
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$json   = array();
if($result = $mysqli->query("select course1 from users where username ='test'")) {
    while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $json[]=array(
            'courses'=>$row['course1'],

        );
    }
}
$result->close();

header("Content-Type: text/json");
echo json_encode(array( 'courses'  =>   $json )); 

$mysqli->close();
```

I can get the first course to show but not the others.  I've tried `select * from users where username ='test'` but I'm stuck on the passing along the array.

Comment: What are you expecting to see and what you see actually?

Comment: isnt `$json[]=array(
            'courses'=>$row['course1'],

        );
` causing the `$json` array to be overwritten ?

Comment: @Clyde : no, it will push new array to the existing $json[]

Comment: @Gaurav : thanx , its been ages since have coded something useful in php ;)

Comment: Why don't you try `echo mysql_num_rows($result);` to check the number of rows returned ?

Comment: @galymzhan I'm expecting to eventually seen all of the courses in the array. Even when I call each course separately in the array it only returns "object Object"

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your database has wrong design.

These courses should be stored in a separate table, not in the users table.
And then it can be easily retrieved.

To answer more certainly, more data of your database structure is required.

Answer (score 0):

What if you're doing something like that:

```
<?php
...
$json = array();
$json['courses'] = array();
if($result = $mysqli->query("select course1 from users where username ='test'")) {
    while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $json['courses'][] = $row['course1'];
    }
}
...
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list only courses, you don't need to all these lines.

```
while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $json[]=array(
        'courses'=>$row['course1'],

    );
}
```

this will be enough

```
while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $json[]= $row['course1'] ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to perform this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","username","password","sampleTest");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Can't connect to SQL Server. Error Code %s\n", mysqli_connect_error($mysqli));
    exit;
}
// Set the default namespace to utf8
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$json   = array();
if($result = $mysqli->query("select * from users where username ='test'")) {
    while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $json[]=array(
            'courses'=> array(
                  'cource1' => $row['course1'],
                  'cource2' => $row['course2'],
                  'cource3' => $row['course3'],
            ),
        );
    }
}
$result->close();
header("Content-Type: text/json");
echo json_encode(array( 'courses'  =>   $json )); 
$mysqli->close();
```

Assuming that you have the users table with fields named 'course1','course2','course3' etc  and 'username'.
You can perform * or just list required fields (comma-separated) after SELECT keyword in the sql query.
For example, you have one user with name test:

```
username course1 course2 course3
  test     Yes     Yes     No
```

You'll receive just one row from the table.
You'll get

```
//var_dump($json);

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["cources"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["cource1"]=>
      string(3) "Yes"
      ["cource2"]=>
      string(3) "Yes"
      ["cource3"]=>
      string(2) "No"
    }
  }
}
```

after performing the code above.
Then you just need to json_encode() this array.
Hope that it'll help.

Comment: This returned "object Object" for me. Not the courses as an array

Comment: I haven't mentioned that the chunk of code above has to be inserted in your code. I've edited my code above